# WinForms - is there an event captured for changed children controls by a containing panel?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, event-handling

I have a panel and in it are a couple of text boxes, I want to decide if to enable a button (also inside the panel) by the values of the the text boxes.

Is there a predefined event the panel is registered to that captures the inner text-boxes onTextChange event?

Thanks,
Shuky

Comment: I like the registering an event idea, how can I perform this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you have to do it yourself (subscribe to the event on the text boxes).

Answer (score 1):

I'd just set up one generic `TextBox_TextChanged` Event handler that calls my `Validate` method and then link every `TextBox` to it, which could be done with a loop.

Maybe something like (not tested):

```
 foreach (Control ctrl in container.Controls)
 {
   if (ctrl is TextBox)
   {
     ((TextBox)ctrl).TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(TextBox_TextChanged);
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't (AFAIK). But you can make all of your text boxes use call the same method when the event occurs. If you want to add text boxes dynamically, you might register for the ControlAdded event and in there in turn register on the freshly added textbox.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike in HTML DOM, events in WinForms are not propagated to containing elements, so you'll have to listen to all the events yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Some Windows controls send a EN_CHANGE message to their parents when their value is modified.

By overriding the parent WndProc method, you can detect when the a child control (text box or combo) changes. e.g.:

```
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == WinUser.WM_COMMAND)
        {
            int wNotCode = HIWORD(wParam);
            if (wNotCode == WinUser.CBN_SELCHANGE || wNotCode == WinUser.EN_CHANGE)
            {
               // Child field has changed
            }
        }

        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
```

Note: this only works with child controls. If you want to process and EN_CHANGE notifications in a root control, you must propagate the WM_COMMAND message upwards.